# Are files data structures?

Tags: data-structures

I'm new to programming and I'd like to know if files such as BMPs, MP3s, EXEs are considered to be data structures as well.

I'm new to programming and I'd like to know if files such as BMPs, MP3s, EXEs are considered to be data structures as well.

Comment: Files are not data structures, but they can be containers to hold data structures.  They can however also hold unstructured data (such as text).

Comment: @fuz thanks man. Yes I have noticed this in my observations from viewing files using a hex editor.

Comment: @fuz Atually, files are always fundementally data structures as a set of contiguous bytes of data stored as-is on disk.

You can further interpret abstract data types from this by defining the encoding strategy of said bytes. For, example if you define the encoding to be ASCII or UTF-8, then you can interpret single bytes, or subsets of contiguous bytes, as textual characters. Though, keep in mind that non-textual encoding strategies exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are some form of compressed(or not) data that should be read on any kind of program that can read them.

But they are structured data. That means you have some specific way your program should read them. For example, in bmp you should know how to read its width and height of the image, then start reading its pixels. Then you continue looping it until its over.

There is more complexes structured datas, as exe's, which your operating system reads, or mp3 which you have to execute some algorithms to make the data understandable

Data structures are actually some default way to think about how to store and read your data and use them for specific situations, such as a command history.

The well known command `CTRL+Z`, `CTRL+SHIFT+Z`, (undo & redo), they are implemented as stacks, which means each command is piled up one above the other, when undoing you will need to take the command that is topmost in the stack, pop it and execute its undo function.

Comment: Thanks man. This definitely sheds some light. I get it so basically Files are structured data and data structures are beyond my understanding as a beginner. I've been making files using a hex editor so this is my only form of experience with writing files. Thanks again

Comment: Saying the data is structured, but not part of some data structure is a logical fallacy.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Frow Wikipedia, "In computer science, a data structure is a data organization, management, and storage format that enables efficient access and modification. More precisely, a data structure is a collection of data values, the relationships among them, and the functions or operations that can be applied to the data, i.e., it is an algebraic structure about data."

You normally read or write such files as a whole and do not perform local modifications. Anyway, for some formats (such as TIFF images for instance), the individual data fields can be accessed directly rather than sequentially.

Comment: You can definitely read files in piece-meal fashion via buffers. This is made possible by the file system data structure that you are accessing via your programming language.

This is how text editors read files, how media players play movies, etc. It's essential in any domain where the data you are actively working with is merely a subset of the entire group of data it forms a part of.

Answer (score 0):

A file system is a data structure that you can interact with via it's associated abstract data type in your programming language of choice.

A file is a group of data within the file system data structure.

You can further think of a file as a data structure in it's own right with it structuring bytes of data in contiguous fashion, with further potential abstract data types depending on the encoding strategy of these bytes.

Even a byte is a data structure, structuring 8 bits of data in contiguous fashion (little endian or big endian style). Your programming language might have an abstract data type for these which gives access to operations on them, which is part of what makes something a data structure.

A single bit might be thought of as the base-case of all data structures when it comes to digital computers, being a non-data structure in the same way that the number zero is a digit that is really a placeholder non-digit (or a digit without a value).

You can't really work with files directly. Whenever you are dealing with directories (which form part of the data structure) and files, you are always dealing with these via the file system data structure that manages them.

Wikipedia entry on File Systems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system

Wikipedia entry on Abstract Data Types: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type